# Run Task scheduler at every 2 minute

Tags: c#

I want to create Task Scheduler that trigger at every 2 minute.
I am using following  namesapce

using Microsoft.Win32.TaskScheduler

I have written following code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Win32.TaskScheduler;

namespace SchedulerTest1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Get the service on the local machine
            using (TaskService ts = new TaskService())
            {
                // Create a new task definition and assign properties
                TaskDefinition td = ts.NewTask();
                td.RegistrationInfo.Description = "Does something";

                // Create a trigger that will fire the task at this time every other day
                td.Triggers.Add(new DailyTrigger());

                // Create an action that will launch Notepad whenever the trigger fires
                td.Actions.Add(new ExecAction("notepad.exe", "D:\\test.log", null));

                // Register the task in the root folder
                ts.RootFolder.RegisterTaskDefinition(@"Test", td);

                // Remove the task we just created
                ts.RootFolder.DeleteTask("Test");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want to run task at every 2 minute. What need to required to update in my code?
Help me

Answer (score 10):

I just had the same challenge. 
Basically you create a TimeTrigger and set the interval like so:

```
    // Get the service on the local machine
    using (var ts = new TaskService())
    {
      // Create a new task definition and assign properties
      TaskDefinition td = ts.NewTask();
      td.Settings.MultipleInstances = TaskInstancesPolicy.IgnoreNew;          
      td.RegistrationInfo.Description = "FTP, Photo and Cleanup tasks";

      // Create a trigger that will execute very 2 minutes. 
      var trigger = new TimeTrigger();
      trigger.Repetition.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2);                    
      td.Triggers.Add(trigger);         

      // Create an action that will launch my jobs whenever the trigger fires
      td.Actions.Add(new ExecAction(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location, null, Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location)));

      // Register the task in the root folder
      ts.RootFolder.RegisterTaskDefinition(@"My Task Name", td);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know in code but... you need specify frequency. Run this on the command line:

> schtasks /create /SC MINUTE /MO 2 /TN DoThis /tr "notepad d:\test.log"

this should repeat every 2 mins (on cmd line).

Comment: If you were to run this on the command line...:

schtasks /create /SC MINUTE /MO 2  /TN DoThis /tr "notepad d:\test.log"

Comment: Presumably you can set the SC and MO somewhere on the object properties. :)

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using the [Task Scheduler Managed Wrapper](http://taskscheduler.codeplex.com) library, I suggest you consult the documentation for [Triggers](http://taskscheduler.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=TriggerSamples&referringTitle=Documentation). More specifically, read the example of how the `TimeTrigger` class is used and how you can use it to specify a repetition interval.

Comment: but how to hide taskeng.exe window when running created task?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to trigger on specific time why dont you use services,
Which will trigger every 2min automatically your pc starts,
for example

```
Timer timer = new Timer();

protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {

        //handle Elapsed event
        timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnElapsedTime);

        //This statement is used to set interval to 2minute (= 60,000 milliseconds)

        timer.Interval = 120000;

        //enabling the timer
        timer.Enabled = true;


    }
 private void OnElapsedTime(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
       // writr code here for 
      //run your Note pad file using process.start or using batch file
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Providing an updated answer for Task Scheduler v2.0.

You can no longer have a task repeat at an interval of less than 5 minutes, but you could always register the task multiple times with the StartBoundary offset by some number of minutes to get the exact repetition pattern that you need.  Be sure to change the name in regTask parameters, if you decide to do this or else the registration will just update the previously registered task.

Apologies for the extra using references below, I pulled this from a larger module and didn't want to take the time to figure out which aren't needed for the code below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Microsoft.Win32;
using TaskScheduler;

private void CreateWindowsTask()
{
    TaskScheduler.TaskScheduler ts = new TaskScheduler.TaskScheduler();
    ts.Connect(null, null, null, null); //connect to local machine as current user
    ITaskDefinition task = ts.NewTask(0);
    task.RegistrationInfo.Author = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
    task.RegistrationInfo.Description = "Put your desription here";

    ITrigger trigger = (ITrigger)task.Triggers.Create(_TASK_TRIGGER_TYPE2.TASK_TRIGGER_DAILY);
    trigger.Id = "MyTimeTrigger";
    string StartTime = "T" + DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:MM:00");
    trigger.StartBoundary = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + StartTime;
    trigger.EndBoundary = DateTime.Now.Date.AddYears(2).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "T12:00:00";
    trigger.Repetition.Interval = "PT5M";   //5 minutes
    trigger.Repetition.Duration = "P1D";    //repeat for 1 day
    trigger.Repetition.StopAtDurationEnd = true;

    IExecAction action = (IExecAction)task.Actions.Create(_TASK_ACTION_TYPE.TASK_ACTION_EXEC);
    action.Id = "MyAction";
    action.Path = "C:\\Windows\\System32\\notepad.exe";

    ITaskFolder root = ts.GetFolder("\\");
    IRegisteredTask regTask = root.RegisterTaskDefinition(
        "Task Scheduler Demo",
        task,
        (int)_TASK_CREATION.TASK_CREATE_OR_UPDATE,
        null, null, //user, passwrod
        _TASK_LOGON_TYPE.TASK_LOGON_INTERACTIVE_TOKEN,
        ""          //sddl
        );
    IRunningTask runTask = regTask.Run(null);
}
```